# Backpropagation problems

Tags: backpropagation

I want to make a financial forecasting applications, these applications implement the backpropagation algorithm. in this case I am using XOR as an example. I want to find the best weight on the input, bias, output. and I have done. but when at umpteenth iteration, I find that the multiplication of the weights on hidden-output and bias weighting produce 0. value of hidden-output weights =-5.92878775009E-323 and the weight bias = 0.00310811260635. is type of data problem? can i convert to other type until i can get value?  because I declared hidden-output weights as null, like "public $w = null". i built these application on php. please, i need help for my final task..

Answer (score 0):

i am working on hybrid neuro fuzzy NN for financial forecasting as well. while training u must always have some limit for iteration. but above all u need more data. as it is always said **THE BEST NN IS NOT ONE WITH BEST ALGORITHM BUT THE ONE WITH MORE TRAINING DATA** please clearify about multiplication of weight. i suggest u took for the activation function u have used